# length of vector after multiplying it by a unit vector

Tags: vectors

Why is it true that:

$w_t \cdot w^* \le \|w_t\|$, if $w^*$ is a unit vector? [$w_t$ and $w^*$ are obviously vectors]

My question is about [this](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~avrim/ML10/lect0125.pdf) article (end of page 2, before the discussion).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember the formula $w_t \cdot w^* = \|w_t\|\|w^*\|\cos(\theta)$.  We know that $\|w^*\|=1$ and $-1 \le \cos(\theta) \le 1$, so the result follows.

Comment: This response is a good standard, but note that in n- dimensional spaces, and more in infinite dimensional, it's not easy to define the angle $\theta$, and we can state the existence of such angle only thanks to Cauchy-ScHwarz inequality.

Comment: @EmilioNovati I guessed that would be over the head of OP.  Also, as for your answer (which I can't comment on because I don't have enough rep), $\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i$ is not the general formula for the inner product on a Hilbert space (because there is no general formula for *any* Hilbert space).  So, if you wanted to do this in its more general form, I would have written the first line simply as $|\langle \mathbf x, \mathbf y \rangle|^2 \le \langle \mathbf x,\mathbf x\rangle^2 \langle \mathbf y,\mathbf y\rangle^2$.  But that's just me.

Answer (score 1):

In a Hilbert space this a consequence of the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) that states:

$$
\left|\sum_{i=1}^n{x_iy_i} \right|^2\le\sum_{i=1}^n{x_i^2}\sum_{i=1}^n{y_i^2}  
$$

So, given  two vectors $\mathbf{v}=\sum_{i=1}{v_i\mathbf{e_i}}$ and $\mathbf{u}=\sum_{i=1}{u_i\mathbf{e_i}}$ for the  the dot product defined as:
$$
\mathbf{x}\cdot \mathbf{y}=\sum_{i=1}{x_i y_i}
$$
we have:
$
\mathbf{v}\cdot \mathbf{u}\le \|\mathbf{v}\| \|\mathbf{u}\|
$  and if $\|\mathbf{u}\|=1$ we find your result. Note that the C-S inequality can be extended also to infinite dimensional vector space.

Comment: You wrote $||v||\,||u||$, coded as ||v||\,||u||, with space inserted manually between $||v||$ and $||u||$.  But if you write $\|v\|\|u\|$, coded as \|v\|\|u\|, then proper spacing automatically results, and $||v||$ looks different from $\|v\|$.  I edited accordingly. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: thanks, I do not know these tricks.